# Can you still battle a monster even if it will not pursue you?

Tags: munchkin

Can you still battle a monster even if it will not pursue you due to low level?

For example, if I'm level 1 and am fighting a monster that "Will not purse anyone level 2 or below."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely.

"Will not pursue anyone of level X or below" is a rule that only affects your potential to run away from the monster, it does not prevent you from facing or killing the monster.

However it does leave you with an easy way out in case your friends do decide to power the monster up (not likely at level 1 or 2, but it may still happen).

From [the official FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/):

> Q. I'm fighting a monster that says "Will not pursue anyone of Level X or below." I'm below that Level; can I still fight the monster?
>
> A. You certainly can fight the monster. If you do not win the combat and have to Run Away, you escape automatically (no roll required).